# max number of clients reached if more than 4 workers redistogo nano heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, celery, redistogo

I know this question is already answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070115/maximum-clients-reached-on-heroku-and-redistogo-nano) , but where did he get that >= 5 redis connections will trigger a max connection error. This on heroku [link](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/redistogo) it says max connections equals to 10. And I never seen in the documentation that there is a limit of 4 at a time. So what if I upgrade to redistogo micro, what is the maximum limit of workers at a time? I know i can buy this and experiment but I don't want to cash out just like that without knowing its limits.

Comment: Seems like I am running into the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999506/how-do-you-deal-with-an-exception-raised-by-celery-not-your-code Have you fixed this?